# Single lambda, multiple cloudwatch log groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

After we run an AWS lambda, a single cloudwatch log group is populated. Is there a way we can populate two (different) cloudwatch log groups from a single AWS lambda? I searched about it but couldn't find an answer. Let me know if it is possible.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the reason? Is it separate env's

Comment: So I want to populate logs in two cloudwatch after a lambda runs. In one cloudwatch, I'll be retrieving some log info for use and then delete that log to avoid duplication. And the other cloudwatch will remain as it is just in case i want to have a look at it afterwards. The env is probably same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to specify two log groups from single lambda.
If you need logs in two cloudwatch groups, you would need to be innovative and create subscription filter in cloudwatch group which stream logs to another lambda where you get logs as a payload and then from the second lambda you can save logs to another cloudwatch group.
More info about cloudwatch subscriptions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html

Answer (score -1):

It is possible: You can use a custom logger that logs to a second log group. See my anwser on this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101977/redirect-aws-lambda-logs-to-a-particular-log-group-in-cloudwatch/77214307#77214307) here.

Comment: Please do **not** post links to other SO threads as answers; flag the question as a possible duplicate instead.