# How to setup Cloudwatch log for a Lambda created in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

After creating a Lambda function in Cloudformation, I would like to be able to setup the Cloudwatch Logs expiration in the same Cloudformation script.

eg:

```
MyLambdaRole:
  Type: AWS::Iam::Role
    ...
    Properties:
      ...
      Policies:
        -
          PolicyName: "myPolicy"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
                  - "logs:CreateLogStream"
                  - "logs:PutLogEvents"
                Resource: "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"

MyLambda:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    ...
    Role: !GetAtt [ MyLambdaRole, Arn ]
```

However, CloudFormation does not allow to modify/update Logs that are reserved for AWS: "Log groups starting with AWS/ are reserved for AWS."

Is there a workaround for this? Since there is no way to setup the log name in the [Lambda resource creation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#w2ab2c21c10d846c11), maybe there is some way to specify it in the Role definition I can't find.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231592/specify-log-group-for-an-aws-lambda

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this and use `RetentionInDays` attribute to change the logs expire after time

```
LogGroup:
  Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
  Properties:
    LogGroupName: !Join ['/', ['/aws/lambda', !Ref MyLambda]]
    RetentionInDays: 7 # days
```

Note: the issue of the LogGroup failing to create will appear if the log group name already exists( will exist if MyLambda already exists). The workaround would be to delete and create stack.

Comment: Note this is not possible for [API GW Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/view-cloudwatch-log-events-in-cloudwatch-console.html): `Do not manually API Gateway API log groups or streams...This is because API Gateway creates log groups or log streams for an API stage at the time when it is deployed`

Comment: Just tested that at the moment, it's possible to create an API GW Log at least,  if the Log does not exist.

Comment: that's why I added `if the log group name already exists` there

Comment: Yes, but the workaround of deleting would only work if the log was first created from the stack. The post was about `modify/update Logs` for a resource that was not in the stack in the first place, it's automatically created by AWS, so just adding this comment after testing that the log was deleted manually and then the stack created.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. As you wrote, it's a log group owned by AWS and you can't give yourself more permissions in a role than AWS would allow. Therefore, you can't allow yourself to modify their log group.

Comment: This is incorrect, I can modify the log group through the awscli with the [put-retention-policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/put-retention-policy.html) command. I guess it seems that only cloudformation is limited so far.

Comment: Never thought about that, thanks. If I have a good answer, I'll try again

Answer (score -3):

Use the AWS Serverless application Model, takes care of the deployment, roles and logs outbox and you always can add your custom cloudformation code https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model
they already have a lot of examples ready to go.

Comment: I can't find where that tool does the specific thing I ask in the question, the [example](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/develop/examples/apps/cloudwatch-logs-to-loggly/template.yaml) for cloudwatch logs looks pretty much like using cloudformation script directly

Comment: The sam template takes care of the IAM role, and configuration of cloudwatch logs, that is the reason why looks so simple

Comment: Ok, can you please add an example to the answer? I can't find where the cloudwatch log would be configured with an "expiry days" number.

Comment: It looks like the [function resource](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/develop/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction) in SAM, doesn't have a way to configure the lambda log group expiry date.