# How to write into a specific CloudWatch group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-application-model

I have a `cloudwatch` log group named **myTestLogGroup** that has a log stream named **myTestLogStream**.

I also have a lambda named **myTestLambda** with the following code:

```
exports.handler = async () => {
    console.log('Hello World!');
    return 200;
}
```

I would like to see the "Hello World" within the specified **myTestLogGroup** instead of the default lambda cloudwatch log group.

How can I achieve this? Any SAM templates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify log group for an AWS lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231592/specify-log-group-for-an-aws-lambda)

Comment: Note, one of the answers there (other than the selected one) specifies doing so through a CloudFormation template for a specific Lambda log group, which could help you out

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible using `console.log` statements.

The log group will always be named `/aws/lambda/<function name>` where you will find log streams per container executions (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html).

By using a custom logging solution you could be able to make API calls to CloudWatch Logs to log in your group/stream using a combination of `CreateLogGroup`, `CreateLogStream` and `PutLogEvents`. This seems like a really complicated solution which brings no real added value.

Comment: one potential benefit of a new log group is isolating security logs from execution/debugging logs. I agree that it's probably not terribly useful for anyone operating outside of a high security environment.