# CDK adds random parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

So I have this function I'm trying to declare and it works and deploys just dandy unless you uncomment the `logRetention` setting. If `logRetention` is specified the cdk deploy operation
adds additional parameters to the stack. And, of course, this behavior is completely unexplained in the documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-lambda-readme.html#log-group

```
SingletonFunction.Builder.create(this, "native-lambda-s3-fun")
                        .functionName(funcName)
                        .description("")
                        // .logRetention(RetentionDays.ONE_DAY)
                        .handler("app")
                        .timeout(Duration.seconds(300))
                        .runtime(Runtime.GO_1_X)
                        .uuid(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                        .environment(new HashMap<String, String>(){{
                            put("FILE_KEY", "/file/key");
                            put("S3_BUCKET", junk.getBucketName());
                        }})
                        .code(Code.fromBucket(uploads, functionUploadKey(
                                "formation-examples",
                                "native-lambda-s3",
                                lambdaVersion.getValueAsString()
                        )))
                        .build();
```

```
"Parameters": {
    "lambdaVersion": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "AssetParametersceefd938ac7ea929077f2e2f4cf09b5034ebdd14799216b1281f4b28427da40aS3BucketB030C8A8": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "S3 bucket for asset \"ceefd938ac7ea929077f2e2f4cf09b5034ebdd14799216b1281f4b28427da40a\""
    },
    "AssetParametersceefd938ac7ea929077f2e2f4cf09b5034ebdd14799216b1281f4b28427da40aS3VersionKey6A2AABD7": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "S3 key for asset version \"ceefd938ac7ea929077f2e2f4cf09b5034ebdd14799216b1281f4b28427da40a\""
    },
    "AssetParametersceefd938ac7ea929077f2e2f4cf09b5034ebdd14799216b1281f4b28427da40aArtifactHashEDC522F0": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Artifact hash for asset \"ceefd938ac7ea929077f2e2f4cf09b5034ebdd14799216b1281f4b28427da40a\""
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/8519). They're [Working On It™](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3463). So, rejoice - we can probably expect a fix sometime within the next decade.

---

I haven't tried it yet, but I'm guessing the workaround is to [manipulate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_raw) the low-level [`CfnLogGroup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-logs.CfnLogGroup.html) construct, since it has the authoritative `retentionInDays` property. The relevant high-level Log Group construct can probably be obtained from the Function via its [logGroup property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.Function.html#loggroup). Failing that, the LogGroup can be created from scratch (which will probably be a headache all on its own).

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the problem described above. From what I can tell, we are [unable to specify a log group name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39233203/1607786) and thus the log group name is predictable.

My solution was to simply create a LogGroup with the same name as my Lambda function with the `/aws/lambda/` prefix.

Example:

```cs
var function = new Function(
    this,
    "Thing",
    new FunctionProps
    {
        FunctionName = $"{Stack.Of(this).StackName}-Thing",
        // ...
    });

_ = new LogGroup(
    this,
    "ThingLogGroup",
    new LogGroupProps
    {
        LogGroupName = $"/aws/lambda/{function.FunctionName}",
        Retention = RetentionDays.ONE_MONTH,
    });
```

This does not create unnecessary "AssetParameters..." CF template parameters like the inline option does.

Note: I'm using CDK version 1.111.0 and 1.86.0 with C#

Comment: The solution of @Robert Hodgen works for me. I am using CDK version 1.97.0 with Python. For me, after defining the Lambda, when defining the LogGroup, I could refer to the name of the function. No need for specifying a hardcoded name within the definition Lambda. In the generated CloudFormation it uses a Ref to the Lambda Function.