# is it possible to update the Lambda stack to change Lambda's log group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a Lambda along with the Cloud Watch log group using Cloud Formation stack few months back.
Now for some reason, I am trying to change Lambda's Log Group to the new one by updating the Log Group name in Cloud Formation template. Stack update is successful with the change but the Lambda still creating and writing the logs to the old log group.

I also tried by changing Log Group's reference variable name used for "DependsOn" in Cloud Formation template but still no luck.

Comment: The log group is named `/aws/lambda/<function name>`. Not clear that you can change it, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231592/specify-log-group-for-an-aws-lambda.

Comment: Ok Then Lambda and Lambda's log group names can't be different.